# Any luck with importing CODA files?

Tags: civibanking

We installed CiviBanking 0.80 on a Drupal 9/CiviCRM 5.33. Then tried to import configs from https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking/tree/master/configuration_database/Importer/CODA but it fails with 'Import/update failed: Import failed: Expected one OptionValue but found 0'

Trying to create the plugin in the interface with the code provided in the examples doesn't help either.

I really feel I must be missing something very obvious here but what ...?

Answer (score 2):

You also need to install the coda extension: https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.coda (check the installation instruction).
Once you have done that you should be able to add a Coda configuration and import a Coda file.

Please note that Coda is a Belgian thing so folks here might not recognize your question :-)

Comment: Oh what is that red thing in the corner over there? Oh yes ... it is me full of shame. Found it! Thank you Erik!

Comment: After installing (following procedure here: https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.coda/issues/2) I do get an error though:
Error: Cannot access private property Codelicious\Coda\Statements\Statement::$transactions in CRM_Banking_PluginImpl_Importer_CODA->import_file() (line 97 of modules/civicrm-ext/org.project60.coda/CRM/Banking/PluginImpl/Importer/CODA.php).

Comment: Did you do the composer install and clear all your caches afterwards? It works fine in all my local and customer environments where they use Coda (5 at the moment)....

Comment: I did, but at first I ran composer inside the extension folder. As this did not load I added the library to my general composer and it was picked up, but resulting in the above error.

Instead I now added  if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../../../../vendor/autoload.php')) {
  require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../../vendor/autoload.php';
}
which seems to work

Comment: Cool, glad it works :-)